# URL link defined in a column, APEX 18.2 IG

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid where one of the columns is a url link to a picture.

Now I want some way to click on that link and open up that link.

Except the URL links in APEX demand a static link. Also, they open up over the open window, instead of another window or another tab.

I have gone through my options, googled for a couple hours, tried to perhaps find a solution that used a DA after clicking on the field and then a JS to redirect to the URL. But my google-fu is apparently not strong enough, and so I turn to you, good people of Stackoverflow.

What I want is a link inside an interactive grid which when clicked, redirects to a URL that it gets from a column in the IG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set you link column like this.
"ENAME" is a column.

[image]

Example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=150297:30:::NO:::

Comment: Thank you, such a simple thing, that I have in fact used before. But it just didnt come to mind that this might be an option in my situation.